# Differential equation non linear first order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, economics

Can you find the solution of that equation please? I don't know how to solve it. I use it to solve a dynamic system in macroeconomics for my homework.
$$\frac{dy}{dt} = y^3 + 1$$

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/

Answer (score 1):

$$\int \frac{dy}{1+y^3}=\int dt$$
the only difficult part in ye question is to find $$\int \frac{dy}{1+y^3}$$
which is
$$\int \frac{dy}{(1+y)^3-3y(1+y)}$$
substitute $1+y=t$. then the integral becomes
$$\int \frac{dt}{t^3-3t(t-1)}$$
$$\int \frac{dt}{t(t^2-3t+3)}$$
now convert the integrand to partial fractions and evaluate.
$$\frac{1}{t(t^2-3t+3)}=\frac{A}{t} +\frac{Bt+C}{(t^2-3t+3)}$$
find $A,B and C$.further evaluate.

Comment: ok good idea i didn't thought to do like that thanks! i will try it

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You can use separation, and then integrate. Try that.

Comment: ok thanks for the web site ;)